# Best way to convert/port other platform games developed in other languages like C++ etc in iphone?

Tags: iphone, c++, game-engine

In order to port games in to iphone, I dont thing complete Objective C coding is required. As I have seen most popular games which were on other devices or on other platform. Now converting exactly to iphone.

Is it there any tool for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different tools out there that allow you to develop once and deploy to multiple platforms.  Some of these are full engines, like [UDK](http://www.udk.com/), [Torque](http://www.garagegames.com/products/torque-3d), and the aforementioned [Unity](http://unity3d.com/).  There are also tools like [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) and [Adobe Air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/), which allow you to develop using web technologies, and then convert to mobile apps.

Of course, sometimes you have to just write your code using C++ and OpenGL, and port it to each platform individually.  This will allow for a bit more control and performance in some cases, and might allow for better access to the API of each device, but the trade off is that it'll take a bit of time to port.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is easiest accomplished by creating a platform independant C/C++ library which can than be linked to from Objective C or loaded with JNI on Android systems.

But I don't think that there is a translator for languages, since the APIs are very different.

Another option is to create the game with a language independent game engine like [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) (which is commercial btw).